# Where can I find Tome of the Clear Mind?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Since getting to level 90, I have noticed that in the Talents/Glyphs screen it states I no longer need 'Dust of Disappearance' to reset my abilities and glyphs, but instead need 'Tome of the Clear Mind'.

Where can I find Tome of the Clear Mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be made by your local friendly scribe, or purchased from most reagent vendors.

Answer (score 1):

I bought these from a reagent vendor that was on a [mammoth](http://www.wowhead.com/item=44234/reins-of-the-travelers-tundra-mammoth).

So I assume any reagent vendor.